# Where can I get unscented deodorant spray in South Korea?

Tags: shopping, south-korea, seoul

I found that my deodorant spray is close to empty so I decided to get it in South Korea before leaving my country.

However, it seems that there are only deodorant spray available that smells in South Korea (e.g. Nivea, etc, which is sold at Watsons, Olive, or GS25).

It is definitely a list of necessities in my travel items, which I regret so much not to carry with me whatever means I take.

So is there any store that sells unscented deodorant spray in South Korea, specifically in Seoul (I stay in Gangnam region if it's relevant)?

Comment: Unperfumed men's deodorant spray is uncommon everywhere. Look in the women's section.

Comment: @OP another place where you can check is pharmacy stores

Comment: Ask for deodorant for people with allergies, those are usually without parfums.

Comment: You can buy undecented spray from supermarkets and convenient stores.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which store sells items like that in Seoul, but you can definitely order [unscented deodorant](http://gsearch.gmarket.co.kr/Listview/Search?keyword=unscented%20deodorant) online:

[image]

Perhaps try checking out which unscented deodorants are sold in online stores and then go shopping with those brand names in mind.

Comment: Oh it's so expensive! Unfortunately I just left South Korea yesterday, so can't check it now...

Comment: @Blaszard there are some cheaper options: http://gsearch.gmarket.co.kr/Listview/Search?keyword=unscented%20deodorant. But generally it does seem to be expensive.

Comment: @ZachLipton I've replaced the screenshot with a reasonably priced option :)